# Use Powershell Core 6 as the default shell with shortcut Windows+X, I

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, powershell-6.0

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1289452/how-do-i-replace-powershell-5-with-powershell-6-as-my-system-default) which isn't quite the same thing. I have Powershell Core 6 installed. I usually open Powershell with the shortcut <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and then <kbd>I</kbd>. Now I would like that shortcut to open Powershell Core 6 instead of the old Powershell 5. Is that possible?

Comment: @vssher - You should submit a detailed answer instead of a temporary comment.

Comment: @vssher that's not going to work for what I want. You see, the shortcut "Windows+X" actually brings up a menu, which lots of useful stuff in it, and I don't want to override "Windows+X" to do something else.

Comment: set the default terminal to Windows Terminal and set the default shell in Windows Terminal to PowerShell Core [How to set PowerShell 7 as default and remove other versions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66447566/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just use the new Windows Terminal and add whatever you choose.

> [Windows Terminal (Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
>
> The Windows Terminal is a new, modern, fast, efficient, powerful, and
>   productive terminal application for users of command-line tools and
>   shells like Command Prompt, PowerShell, and WSL. Its main features
>   include multiple tabs, Unicode and UTF-8 character support, a GPU
>   accelerated text rendering engine, and custom themes, styles, and
>   configurations.
>
> This is an open source project and we welcome community participation.
>   To participate please visit https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

***Update based on comments thus far.***

You cannot do what you are after natively. You have to hack the registry to change this.

Yet, why go thru all that effort, when you can just pin the pwsh shortcut to the first position on your taskbar, and then just press Win key + 1 (or where you put it up to position 9) on the taskbar.

For example, on my taskbar, I have Windows Terminal, pwsh, powershell, powershell_ISE, VSCode, PowerShellStudio in position 1,2,3,4,5,6.

[image]

So, pressing Win+#, starts the app. No reg hacking required and 2 keystrokes vs 3. One could even drop the pwsh one since it's included as an option in Windows Terminal if you have Windows Terminal and pswh installed.
[image]

Comment: But can you launch the new terminal with Powershell 6 using the Windows+X, I shortcut?

Comment: I am not getting your point here, as to what tool you are saying you are doing this from. The default response to the combination of WIn+X+I https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts on windows 10 is to open the Settings panel. Unless you've gone in and hacked stuff to add PSCore on that menu and assigned that shortcut. I have had PSCore on my system for a while, and I have a shortcut on my taskbar for all my commonly used tools with hotkeys assigned. I don't mess with that settings menu.  I just use Windows Terminal for any console stuff and ISE/VSC the rest.

Comment: Win+X opens the Quick Link menu, then I opens Powershell 5.  As asked in the question, the OP and I would like this to open Powershell Core 6; opening the Terminal would do the job.  Win+X N opens settings.

Comment: Note my keystroke is combined not separate, hence the difference. You cannot do what you are after natively. You have to hack the registry to change this. Yet, why go thru all that effort, when you can just pin the pwsh shortcut to the first position on your taskbar, and then just press Win key + 1 (or where you put it up to position 9). on the taskbar, I have WinTerm, pwsh, powershell, powershell_ISE, VSCode, PowerShellStudio in position 1,2,3,4,5,6. So, pressing Win+#, starts the app. No reg hacking required.

Comment: Yeppers, been using that for a long time, even before Win10, Yet, know the limit is 1-9, but the hotkeys for anything beyond 1-9 would still be a thing as well.

Comment: @RandyOrrison yes, because you can [set to use Windows Terminal as default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/) and Win+X, I will open Windows Terminal

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool that allows you to edit the Win+X Menu:
https://winaero.com/download-winx-menu-editor-allows-you-to-add-or-remove-winx-menu-items

[image: Screenshot]

Here, there are some groups.
Add it to whatever group you like using the add a program button.
And then, press Restart Explorer (NOTE: This will close all of your file explorer windows!)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1094319)

Answer (score 0):

Another option to @vssher's suggestion would be to use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) or [Microsoft Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal). 
 To set as the default terminal:

- **Microsoft Terminal:** *Windows' Settings* → *Privacy & Security* → *For Developers* → *Terminal*
- **ConEmu [Settings](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html):** <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> → [*Integration*](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html#Integration) → [*Default term*](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html#Default_term):

  - [*Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications*](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2515) 
     Main switch
  - [*Register on OS startup*](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2547) 
     Start automatically at logon via registry
  - [*Aggressive Mode*](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2684) 
     A running ConEmu instance isn't required for hooking new processes, one already hooked process [`explorer.exe`] is enough
  - [*List of hooked executables or window class names*](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2516): `explorer.exe` 
     ConEmu is set as the default terminal via [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks) within the [Windows Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) [`explorer.exe`] and/or any other program, delimited via `|` [pipe]:

    ```powershell
    explorer.exe|devenv.exe|totalcmd.exe|TaskManagerWindow|codeblocks.exe|lazarus.exe|gdb.exe
    ```

    <sup>*(Windows' Settings app has no bearing on ConEmu being set as the default OS terminal due to hooks)*</sup>

---

To configure the hotkey to launch `Pwsh.exe` in ConEmu:

1. [*Settings*](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html) → [*Startup*](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html#Startup) → [*Tasks*](https://conemu.github.io/en/Settings.html#Tasks): *Predefined tasks (command group)*
2. <kbd>+</kbd> icon or use ConEmu's default [`Shells::PowerShell Core`]

   1. **Name** *(shows `Group <#>`)***:** `Powershell::Pwsh`
   2. **Hotkey:** Select whatever you'd like
   3. **Default task for new console:** Default shell whenever you open ConEmu
   4. **Taskbar jump lists:** Adds this task to the ConEmu taskbar jumplist
   5. **Default shell (**<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>**):**

      - ***Windows 10:** Makes this the default in the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu*
      - ***Windows 11:** Doesn't affect <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu*

        - *While the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu could also be manually modified in Win <11, it causes corruption in 11 (if someone knows of a way that doesn't result in corruption, please comment and I'll modify this)*
   6. **Task Parameters:** None are needed, but can be customized
   7. **Commands:**

      ```powershell
      pwsh.exe -NoExit -Command "Import-Module C:\Users\<username>\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1" -new_console:t:"Pwsh"
      ```

      - To launch as an Admin terminal, add `a:` before `t:`: `-new_console:a:t:"Pwsh"`
      - `-Import-Module` is optional, but allows customization of the prompt in `profile.ps1`:

        ```powershell
        #

        # ===========================================================
                ##::[[--- Powershell PS1 Profile ---]]::##
        # ===========================================================

          # Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 || Profile.ps1:
            # %UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell
            # $env:UserProfile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell

        # ================================================================

            # Variables
        #----------------------------------------------------------------
        # ANSI:
          $ESC                              = [char]27

        # Host.PrivateData:
          $PD                               = $($Host.PrivateData)

        # Colors: 
          $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor    = ($bckgrnd = 'Black')
          $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor    = 'Gray'

          $PD.ErrorForegroundColor          = 'Red'
          $PD.ErrorBackgroundColor          = $bckgrnd

          $PD.WarningForegroundColor        = 'Magenta'
          $PD.WarningBackgroundColor        = $bckgrnd

          $PD.DebugForegroundColor          = 'Yellow'
          $PD.DebugBackgroundColor          = $bckgrnd

          $PD.VerboseForegroundColor        = 'Green'
          $PD.VerboseBackgroundColor        = $bckgrnd

          $PD.ProgressForegroundColor       = 'Yellow'
          $PD.ProgressBackgroundColor       = $bckgrnd

        #================================================================

            # Functions
        #----------------------------------------------------------------

        # Prompt:
          Function set-prompt {
            Param (
              [Parameter(Position=0)]
              [ValidateSet("Default","Test")]
              $Action
            )

            switch ($Action) {
              "Default" {
                Function global:prompt {
                  if (test-path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
                    write-host " "
                    write-host ("$ESC[48;2;40;40;40m$ESC[38;2;170;210;0m$(Get-Location) $ESC[0m $ESC[0m")

                  if ( $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle -match "Administrator" ) {
                    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red'
                    $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                      write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                    } else {
                      write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
                    })
                  } else {
                    $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                      write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                    } else {
                      write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
                    })
                  }

                  return " "
                }
              }
            }
          }

          set-prompt Default

        # Relaunch as Admin:
          function Relaunch-Admin { Start-Process -Verb RunAs wt }
          Set-Alias psa Relaunch-Admin
        ```
3. <kbd>**Save settings**</kbd>

---

To import the [`ConEmu.xml`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts+Configs/ConEmu/ConEmu.xml) config I use:

1. GitHub download button: *Download raw file* → Open in text editor
2. Find/Replace `<username>` with the `%UserProfile%` *folder name* →  Save changes
3. Import via ConEmu Settings: <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> → <kbd>**Import...**</kbd> → <kbd>**Save settings**</kbd>

Comment: If downvoting an answer, please leave a comment explaining why, else whatever issue an answer has cannot be corrected.

Comment: `since it's a better terminal manager than anything Microsoft offers` well it's far worse than the Windows Terminal. Especially conemu can't be set as the default terminal. Windows Terminal can

Comment: @phuclv ConEmu is the default terminal on my laptop, has been for years - what are you specifically referring to?

Comment: you can't set the default terminal in Windows Settings like this https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/set-default-terminal-windows-11/?expand_article=1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLopI.png

Comment: @phuclv That setting has no bearing for ConEmu being set as the default terminal - ConEmu does this via hooks within `explorer.exe`, and any other program a user wishes, via ConEmu Settings → _Integration_ → _Default term_ → [_Force ConEmu as default terminal for console applications_](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2515), _Register on OS startup_, [_Aggressive Mode_,](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2684) and specifying `explorer.exe` within [_List of hooked executables or window class names_](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html#id2516)

Answer (score -1):

This is a workaround that I am currently using.

If you use PowerShell's `$PROFILE`, you could insert a line `pwsh.exe` in the beginning of the script. Any shortcuts of Windows to start PowerShell will effectively hook into **PowerShell 6** indirectly as a child process of **PowerShell 5**.

Comment: How can that be done?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.